# How to restore websites in localhost

Tags: c1-cms

I am newbie in Composite, I already backup and download C1 websites (www.solve.sg), I also have installed (and working) Composite in localhost. So how to restore websites in localhost?.

I already used method to rename folder CompositesC1 to CompositesC1old, then extract and put extracted web in CompositeC1 folder at localhost but not working and gave me error.

Please help the right method how to read online backup websites and to read that at localhost

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what Composite is, but you probably need to go back to your cPanel / backend of your webhost, dump the DB powering solve.sg and import that into your local instance.

Your hosting provider will probably have a tool called phpMyAdmin; go in there and find the 'Export' tab at the top of your DB and dump it out as a .sql file. You will then import that file into your local environment, probably also using phpMyAdmin.

You may also have to change around some of the settings files that show where your database is relative to your application.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this is xml web-based, and there is no dbase